# Regex match a spanish word ending with a dot(.) and underscore

Tags: regex, python-2.7

This is the regex I'm trying:

```
([\w\s\/áéíóúüñçåÁÉÍÓÚÜÑÇÐ\-]+)(\.\_)
```

Here are two examples that it should match against:

> EL ROSARIO / ESCUINAPA._ Con poco más de 4 mil pesos...

and

> Cuautitlán._ Con poco más de 4 mil pesos...

The expression works for the first example but not for the second because of encoding probably:

```
docHtml = urllib.urlopen(link).read()

#using the lxml function html
tree = html.fromstring(docHtml)
newsCity = CSSSelector('#pid p')

try:
city_paragraph = newsCity(tree)

city_match = re.search('([\w\s\/áéíóúüñçåÁÉÍÓÚÜÑÇÐ\-]+\._)',city_paragraph[0].text)
```

Comment: Try dropping the `^` in your pattern.

Comment: Why do you have ^? That will only match if the word is the first in the line.

Comment: This doesn't work for you? I just ran this through http://www.regextester.com/ and both examples matched.

Comment: Just edited to include the whole context..

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression appears to be correct. I suspect that the bug is in how you're reading the strings that you're matching against. You want something like:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('spanish.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

```
newsCity = CSSSelector('#tamano5 p')

city_paragraph = newsCity(tree)
city_p = city_paragraph[0].text
city_utf=city_p.encode("utf-8")
city_match = re.search('([\w\s\/áéíóúüñçåÁÉÍÓÚÜÑÇÐ\-]+\._)',city_utf)
```

This gives me the expected result which in this case was to extract the city string using re.search.